# restriction display portlet liferay

Tags: liferay

I work with liferay 5.2

I connected to liferay with this compte  test@amazon.en

this compte has the Administrator role so he can show all page in liferay :

[image]

I want to display same page by role ,

to do this I create new role having this name : **testRole**

my goal is to display only link **Users** that is under **Portal**   to the compte **test@amazon.en**

**Updated :**

I try with another way

I create page named  **pageTest**

this page is under **Supcom**  portlet

this is my portlet which is deployed in liferay

this is the Friendly URL of my page : **pageTest**

**http://com.test:8080/group/Supcom/../control_panel/manage?p_p_id=125&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&doAsGroupId=11003&refererPlid=18603**

I make /../ in order to eliminate **Supcom  portlet** because users portlet is under **control_panel portlet**

this is the real link of users portlet in liferay :

http://com.tes:8080/group/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=125&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&doAsGroupId=11003&refererPlid=18603

my goal as I said is when I click in **pageTest**  I will be forwarded   in Users portlet

but I have an error when I try to save the Friendly URL of **pageTest**

**Please enter a friendly url with valid characters.**

Comment: Take a look at Roles section of https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/5.2/administration/-/ai/using-the-control-panel-1

Comment: Please update: Unless you're on EE, this version did not have any updates for ~5 years now

Comment: thank you for your response, I have updated my question but I also have another erreur